# How To Import S3cmd in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, import, boto3, s3cmd

I am fairly new to python programming. I was trying  to find out the way to import S3cmd like commands or functions  in python, the way we can import Boto3. As I can see s3cmd can only be used from command line. Now, I may use subprocess or os.system, but using a module may provide a lot more flexibility . I am using python 3.

Regards, 
Amit

Answer (score 2):

`s3cmd` is a command line tool (like `AWS CLI`), not a python module. Whatever `s3cmd` does, you can do the same using `Boto3`. In fact `Boto3` is more powerful than `s3cmd`.

You can take a look at s3cmd source code (it's also written in python) and see how it implements its functionality: https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd and https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/blob/master/s3cmd

Comment: @jeffrycopps not sure if the s3cmd modules was available 3 years ago when the question was asked.